# taking max two duplicate columns and removing old ones

Tags: python, pandas

I have two duplicate columns (named cat and dog) and i want to take the max of the duplicate columns to create a new column. How can I do this dynamically in pandas? Not sure how to proceed. i've only tried hard coded solutions so far.

this is the input dataframe.

```
dog dog cat cat
0   1   0   1
0   1   1   0
0   1   0   0
0   0   0   0
1   0   0   1
```

this is the expected output i want.

```
dog cat
1   1
1   1
1   0
0   0
1   1
```

Comment: how did you end up with duplicate columns at the first place? curious to know

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).max()
```

Comment: KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([0], dtype='int64')] are in the [columns]"

Comment: @Eisen what do you get with `print(df.columns)`?